# Isolating string characters

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have the following string:

```
 string=  {{"D(2.00225050736308e-15*A01 - 0.0201549279513608) = \
    0.0820842279730734 + 0.08923448712*delay(A35", 
      " 17) + 0.08669543966*delay(A88", 
      " 20) + 1.98960079968027e-16*A57 - 0.3146216003*erf(delay(A01", 
      " 2)) - 0.3157150548*erf(sin(0.00541313376373593*cos(0.\
    129564165001876 + 2.22963213427193e-15*A57 - \
    gauss(0.00170510841714258 + 1.87338787507e-15*A51)) + delay(A27", 
      " 24) + gauss(gauss(0.00170510841714258 + 1.87338787507e-15*A51)) - \
    2.17740845675611e-15*A81*cos(0.129564165001876 + \
    2.22963213427193e-15*A57 - gauss(0.00170510841714258 + \
    1.87338787507e-15*A51))))"}}
```

I want to isolate all characters within the brackets of the **delay** part e.g. delay(A27, 24). In other words I want the characters A24 and 24. My best bet was to go with

```
StringCases[string,"delay("~~__~~")"]
```

in order to get all String between the brackets, but this does not work. Still a little bit confused about using string patterns :/.

Comment: As @belisarius alluded to, by default `__` and `___` are "greedy" in string patterns -- meaning they will yield the longest possible match. By contrast, in nonstring patterns the default behavior is the opposite. Compare: `StringReplace["abcde", x__ ~~ y__ :> x]` and `Replace[{a, b, c, d, e}, {x__, y__} :> {x}]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Shortest[]` is the easiest way to stop the greedy pattern matching algorithm:

```
StringCases[StringJoin[string], Shortest["delay(" ~~ x__ ~~ " " ~~ y__ ~~ ")"] -> {x, y}]
(* {{"A35", "17"}, {"A88", "20"}, {"A01", "2"}, {"A27", "24"}} *)
```

**Edit:**

As @Öskå showed in his answer, it can be done without using `Shortest[]` too. Here's another way that doesn't need to mess with the string lengths:

```
f = StringFreeQ[#, ")"] &;
StringCases[StringJoin[string], "delay(" ~~ x__?f ~~ " " ~~ y__?f ~~ ")" -> {x, y}]
(* {{"A35", "17"}, {"A88", "20"}, {"A01", "2"}, {"A27", "24"}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
StringCases[StringJoin[string], "delay(" ~~ x : Except[")"] .. ~~ ")" :> StringSplit[x]]
(* {{"A35","17"},{"A88","20"},{"A01","2"},{"A27","24"}} *)
```

or,

```
StringCases[ToString[string], "delay(" ~~ x:Except[")"] .. ~~ ")" :> 
                                 StringSplit[x, ","]]       (*thanks: eldo *)
(* {{"A35", "  17"}, {"A88", "  20"}, {"A01", "  2"}, {"A27", "  24"}} *)
```

Comment: +1 - The first answer I almost understand. You could save 2 characters and a couple of nanoseconds by replacing `StringJoin` with `ToString` :)

Comment: @eldo, thank you. `ToString` makes sense; but it gives extra commas to clean-up.

Comment: @eldo, thanks again. Fixed the comma issue; but it took more than the two extra characters saved with `ToString`:)

Answer (score 2):

Just a solution without `Shortest` because I simply didn't know about it:

```
StringReplace[#, ")" -> ""] & /@ 
  StringCases[StringJoin[string], "delay(" ~~ x__ ~~ " " ~~ y__ ~~ ")" /; 
      (StringLength@x < 5 && StringLength@y < 5) :> {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{"A35", "17"}, {"A88", "20"}, {"A01", "2"}, {"A27", "24"}}
> ```